# Combine a list of lists with a list using a function in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming, nested-lists

I want to be able to apply a function between each element of an input list and each element of each sublist in a list of lists like so:

```
mapFunc :: (a -> b -> c) -> [[a]] -> [b] -> [[c]]
```

For instance: `mapFunc (*) [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]] [1,2,3]` should give me: `[[1,4,9],[4,10,18]]`.

Is there a specific way to do this in Haskell?

I know it probably requires a combination of `zipWith` and `map` in some manner and I have been trying them but not really been able to make any head way into my problem

Comment: Hint: use `zipWith` http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:zipWith

Comment: do you have any code that you tried to write? anything at all.

Comment: Can you write a `(a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]`? And can you change a `x -> a -> y -> z` to `x -> [a] -> y -> [z]`?

Comment: Yes you are right. It is a simple combination of `map` and `zipWith (*)`.

Comment: Observe the values of `zipWith (*) [1,2,3] [1,2,3]` and `zipWith (*) [1,2,3] [4,5,6]`. With that knowledge, do you see how `map` could be used?

Comment: What should happen if the first list is empty? What if the next list is empty? What if the lists or sublists have different lengths?

Comment: I would suggest (and I think this is good general advice while you're learning):1) start by stating the problem very clearly (I should be able to understand what you're asking without looking at an example; sometimes this is half the work of writing the algorithm), 2) write a solution using recursion, 3) try refactoring using higher-order functions

Comment: @jberryman another approach is to provide a comprehensive set of examples so that we can understand the problem just by looking at the examples alone. that could be half of the work of designing the algorithm, as well.  :)  and then the solution can be derived by a straightforward  generalization.

Answer (score 2):

> I know it probably requires a combination of `zipWith` and `map`

You’re on the right track.

Given two lists `xss` and `ys`, you want to take each element of `xss :: [[a]]`, being a list `xs :: [a]`, and zip it with `ys :: [b]` using `f :: a -> b -> c`. “Each element” suggests `map` (or a list comprehension), so you can make a guess containing a “hole” which the compiler will report the type of:

```
mapFunc :: (a -> b -> c) -> [[a]] -> [b] -> [[c]]
mapFunc f xss ys = map (\xs -> _) xss

-- or,
mapFunc f xss ys = [_ | xs <- xss]
```

The type of this hole is `[c]` in either case; the compiler also gives us a list of things in scope that may be useful for filling the hole:

```
xs :: [a]
ys :: [b]
xss :: [[a]]
f :: a -> b -> c
mapFunc :: (a -> b -> c) -> [[a]] -> [b] -> [[c]]
```

Looking at the type of `zipWith` should then make it clear how to fill in this hole, i.e. how to construct a value with the type `[c]` by combining the values you have in scope:

```
zipWith :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
```

As an exercise, you can also manually inline the definitions of `map` and `zipWith` to understand how you would write this using manual recursion. A useful extension here is `{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}`, which allows you to define the scope of the types `a`, `b`, and `c` using a `forall` quantifier, so that you can break the problem down into local definitions and give type signatures for each part such that those type signatures could reuse the same type variables `a`, `b` and `c`. Try it yourself starting with this signature:

```
mapFunc :: forall a b c. (a -> b -> c) -> [[a]] -> [b] -> [[c]]
```

And if you get stuck, there’s a hint below for how I would structure a solution.

> Fill in the blanks:
>
> ```
> mapFunc :: forall a b c. (a -> b -> c) -> [[a]] -> [b] -> [[c]]
> mapFunc f xss ys = mapping xss
>   where
>     mapping :: [[a]] -> [[c]]
>     mapping (xs : xss') = _
>     mapping []          = _
>
>     zipping :: [a] -> [b] -> [c]
>     zipping (x : xs) (y : ys) = _
>     zipping []       _        = _
>     zipping _        []       = _
> ```

Answer (score 0):

So we must have

```
mapFunc (*)  [[1,2,3], [4, 5, 6]]    [1,2,3] 
     ==      [[1,4,9], [4,10,18]]
```

and so, also

```
mapFunc (*)  [[1,2,3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10]]     [1,2,3]
     ==      [[1,4,9], [4,10,18], [7, 14, 27]  ]
-- and
mapFunc (*)  [[1,2,3]]                               [1,2,3] 
     ==      [[1,4,9]]
-- and
mapFunc (*)           [[4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10]]     [1,2,3]
     ==               [[4,10,18], [7, 14, 27]  ]
```

Thus,

```
mapFunc (*) ([[1,2,3]] ++ [[4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10]])    [1,2,3]
     == (mapFunc (*) 
             [[1,2,3]]                                   [1,2,3])
                       ++
             (mapFunc (*) [[4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10]]     [1,2,3])
```

There's nothing special about these specific numbers though, so we must necessarily have

```
mapFunc (*) (    [xs]      ++              xss       )     ys   =
  = (mapFunc (*) [xs]  ys  ++  mapFunc (*) xss  ys)
  = ([g           xs  ys]  ++  mapFunc (*) xss  ys)
```

because as we see from our examples, `(\xss -> mapFunc (*) xss ys)` is a length-preserving transformation.

So what should this `g` function be?

*Lather, rinse, repeat:*

We must have

```
g   [1,2,3]   [1,2,3] == [1,4,9]
g   [4,5,6]   [1,2,3] == [4,10,18]
g   [7,8,9,10]  [1,2,3] == [7,14,27]
```

and thus, again generalizing as the numbers are nothing special in themselves,

```
g  xs  ys  =  [ (*) x y | x <- xs | y <- ys ]
```

and that's that.